# Auto-completion for mime-type entry

Tags: mime-types, vala

I'm looking for a way to have auto-completion on an Gtk.Entry for mime-type.
I'm sure there is a better way than declare

```
const string MIME_TYPES[] = { ... };
```

Maybe using an existing linux (gnome) library dealing with mime-types.

On Arch there is a package called "mime-types" providing the file /etc/mime.types lisintg something like 2000 types.
How can I use this file, is it a good solution or is it to specific to arch ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
string mime = File.new_for_uri(uri).query_info ("standard::content-type", 0, null).get_content_type ();
```